# Javascript custom event change callback argument

Tags: javascript

I want to write a custom event and  print to console obj.name in its callback function

But I get an error and need to get obj name as obj.detail.context.name

How can I solve it and print using obj.name line code instead of obj.detail.context.name

currently the strucure of obj in the callback is:

```
obj
```

CustomEvent 
    {
    isTrusted: false
    }
    bubbles: false
    cancelBubble: false
    cancelable: false
    currentTarget: WindowdefaultPrevented: false
    detail: Object
    eventPhase: 2isTrusted: falseisTrusted: falsepath: Array[1]returnValue: truesrcElement: Windowtarget: WindowtimeStamp: 1446215160435type: "eat:done"**proto**: CustomEvent

Comment: can you provide jsfiddle?

Answer (score 2):

You could augment the `event object` with your custom attributes (merge it with lodash or do it by yourself). The following example maybe gives you some insight;

```
// define the event
var event = new CustomEvent('test');
// add your custom arguments
event.customAttr = 'foo';
//the listener
window.addEventListener('test', function (e) {console.log(e)});
// fire it
window.dispatchEvent(event);
// logs: CustomEvent {isTrusted: false, customAttr: "foo"}
```

Answer (score 2):

When registering a custom event, the returned value when it's triggered is of type CustomEvent.

This confusion is also apparent in your naming. Instead of:

```
MyEventsManager.on('eat:done', function(person){});
```

You're actually getting:

```
MyEventsManager.on('eat:done', function(event){});
```

If you want to use CostumEvents, this is the only way (You can't use custom events without using the CustomEvent object).

Perhaps you're looking for something simpler, like a callback manager:

```
function EventsManager(){
    var callbacks = {};
    return {
        on: function(eventName, callback, context){
            if(callbacks[eventName])
                callbacks[eventName].push(callback.bind(context));
            else
                callbacks[eventName] = [callback.bind(context)];
        },

        trigger: function(eventName, data){
            for(var i=0; callbacks[eventName] && i < callbacks[eventName].length; i++)
                callbacks[eventName][i](data);
        }
    }
}
```